# How to automate filtered data extention

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have salesforce (salesforce report import) data extension let say dataex1, now I have created 2 more filtered data extensions. I have automated dataex1 and scheduled every hour, dataext1 got updated but filtered extension remain same.  Is there a way so filtered extensions get updated as well?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a [Filter Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/filter_activity/) in Interactions for each one of your Data Extensions and Filters.  Then you can add it to your Automation.